# Is it possible to install SQL Server on a Windows Nano server?

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-server-2016, nano-server

I'm playing with Nano server right now and it seems really promising. I can install failover cluster role on Nano servers. I want to know if it's possible to install a SQL Server cluster on Nano server. I google around and seems no one is doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet it isn't. MySQL installs nicely though.

Answer (score 0):

This are some links I found to this subject

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/03/21/sql-server-in-windows-containers

https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/manage/windows-containers/mssql-server-2014-express-windows